# Parameter pack to parameter pack mapping

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I want to remap a parameter pack to a different type parameter pack.
More precisely I have a function:

```
template<typename ...type_pack, typename Function = void(type_pack&&...)>
        constexpr decltype(auto) zip(Function&& op, type_pack&&... pack)
        {
            static_for<0, N_lhs>([&](auto i)
                {
                    op(pack[i]...);
                });
            return;
        }
```

Basically I want to create a parameter pack of the results from applying the `[]` to the pack elements. Note that `i` here is an integral constant, and the static_for is compile time, you can assume that `[]` is `constexpr`. I do not have much control over `op`, so it expects a parameter pack and not a tuple.

Edit:

Seems like I was under the misunderstanding that `op(pack[i]...)` was causing the issue, when in fact this is a legal C++ construct (I thought it was illegal). So it seems like something was actually wrong with my static_for loop. My question was originally regarding `op(pack[i]...)` so I will keep it as is.

I prepared a more general example not using `[]` but a different arbitrary function just for a sanity check: https://godbolt.org/z/h8Hbbt

Is there a place in the standard where this pack expansion behaviour is mentioned - namely the fact that functions may be applied on top?

Comment: You should probably include the definition of `static_for` and show how the function would be called and what's not working to make this a [mcve].

Comment: @super I didn't include static_for since it is somewhat irrelevant to the example. I may have as well called `op(pack[i]...)`. The problem is specifically calling `op(pack[i]...)`, usually one calls `op(pack...)`, but I want to get a parameter pack by apply the operator `[]` to the current parameter pack.

Comment: Is `type_pack` a parameter pack of parameter packs, then?

Comment: @JonHarper In this specific instance, it's made of objects that support a constexpr `[]` operator (it accepts integral constants).

Comment: Why do you have to bother with the type of `Function` at all? Just deduce it from what's passed in.

Comment: @super It's mainly for documentation purposes, so that one (me specifically) would be hinted when reading the code that the return type would be thrown away.

Comment: So the point is to not allow a function with a return value to be passed in? Sorry for the many questions. I just don't follow.

Comment: @super No, the point is to achieve this: `op(pack[i]...);`. I am working on a more concrete example as we speak, I'll update the post in a minute.

Comment: But... you can just do that? `op(pack[0]...);` will call op with the first element from every parameter in the pack.

Comment: @super You are right. It seems I had the misconception that `op(pack[0]...)` was illegal, when in fact the problem is unrelated to it. My question was regarding this specific pack expansion, so I will leave it as it is - I believe I will be able to fix the static loop on my own. Thanks for clarifying that this construct `op(pack[0]...)` is in fact legal.

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) describes it here as *A pattern followed by an ellipsis, in which the name of at least one parameter pack appears at least once*.

Comment: @super You can formulate it as an answer if you want, so I can accept it. Surprisingly C++ seems to be able to do a lot more with pack expansions than what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parameter pack can be expanded in terms of a pattern.

```
template <typename... T>
void test(T... t) {
    (std::cout << ... << static_cast<int>(t));
}
```

Here it is exanded as a folding expression, but it works in the same way in a regular pack expansion. The pattern here is `static_cast<int>(t)` and it will expand to

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(t1) << static_cast<int>(t2) << ... << static_cast<int>(tN);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Basically I want to create a parameter pack of the results from applying the `[]` to the pack elements.

Do you mean something as follows?

```
template <typename ... type_pack,
          typename Function = void(decltype(std::declval<type_pack>()[0])...)>
constexpr decltype(auto) zip(Function&& op, type_pack&&... pack)
 {
   /* ... */
 }
```

Please, prepare a minimal but complete example (`static_for`, mainly) if you want a more tested answer.

Comment: Yes precisely, the definition I have is wrong I believe. That's the main idea, to turn `pack...` into `pack[i]...`, or more generally, to turn `pack...` into `g(pack)...`, where `g` is a constexpr function. The question is not very related to `static_for`, I shouldn't have included it in the first place probably. An `op(pack[0]...)` would have been just as good inside the main function.

Comment: Your answer actually solves a different problem that I had - regarding how to declare the function (a problem I didn't even know I had initially).

Comment: @lightxbulb - "Your answer actually solves a different problem that I had" - better than nothing :-)

Comment: Definitely, it was quite useful.